# Flask migrate does not detect column autoincrement changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I have change my model class with id from autoincrement=False to autoincrement=True but Flask Migrate package does not dectect change to apply to the database? How can I fix this?

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
```

The migrate command log:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.
```

Comment: Probably, you will have to make it by yourself, as migrate does record complete changes made to Models.

Answer (score 3):

The autogenerated migration scripts are not meant to be 100% correct every time, they are meant just as a starter. You should review it, and add or correct anything that is not accurate. So I'd say just add the autoincrement to the script and that should be it.

Comment: Thanks. However, when it does not detect any changes then it even does not create any migration files for us to edit. Then, we have to manually create migrations file, it so annoying :(

Comment: Have you tried using the `revision` command? That generates an empty migration script that you can edit manually.

Comment: I did not. Thank you so much to let me know. Best (y)